# Split rows in ssis based on a field value

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

In SSIS - How can I split data from row into 2 rows
for example :

*FROM :*

```
ID  Data
1   On/Off
2   On/Off
```

*TO :*

```
ID  Data
1   On
1   Off
2   On
2   Off
```

Comment: It depends. Will all rows have two elements, or will some have more or less than that?

Comment: No - just those two rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution Overview

You have to use a script component to achieve this.  Use an unsynchronous output buffer to generate multiple rows from on row based on your own logic.

## Solution Details

1. Add a DataFlow Task
2. In the `DataFlow Task` add a `Flat File Source`, `Script Component`, and a Destination
3. In the Script Component, select `ID`, `Data` columns as Input
4. Go to the `Input and Outputs` page, click on the Output and change the `Synchronous Input` property to `none`
5. Add two Output Columns `ID` and `Data` into the `Output`
6. Change the Script language to `Visual Basic`
7. Inside the Script editor write the following code

   ```
   Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

       Dim strValues() as String = Row.Data.Split(CChar("/")

       For each str as String in strValues

           Output0Buffer.AddRow()
           Output0Buffer.ID = Row.ID
           Output0Buffer.Data = str

       Next


   End Sub
   ```

## Additional Information

For more details follow these links:

- [SSIS - Script Component, Split single row to multiple rows](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6cb66f8a-6527-42b4-a7df-1087ceb6e5e6/ssis-script-component-split-single-row-to-multiple-rows?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
- [Output multiple rows from script component per single row input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627124/output-multiple-rows-from-script-component-per-single-row-input)

---

## Using T-SQL

*Based on your comments, this is a link that contains a n example of how this can be done using a SQL command*

- [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Comment: Thank you , but do you know a script in sql server that do the same ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows

Comment: @TzachiGolan the link i provided is a similar question on how to achieve this using SQL, if you need any help give me a feedback